# Selecting values higher than NOW()

Tags: php, mysql

i have an appointments table and i want to show the user all the appointments he has made that are higher than the current date so he can cancel them...i have this query...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,date,start,end FROM jos_jxtc_appbook_appointments WHERE userident='$idusera' AND CONCAT(date,' ',start)>NOW()");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

echo '<div class="record" id="record-',$row['id'],'">
    <a href="?delete=',$row['id'],'" class="delete">Delete</a>
    <strong>',$row['date'], $row['start'], $row['end'],'</strong>
  </div>';

}
```

and this still shows dates lower than the current...is it maybe a timezone error or something like that?

this is my table...

```
   date     duration    start     end
2013-02-28  01:00:00  12:00:00  13:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  03:00:00  04:00:00
2013-02-27  01:00:00  21:00:00  22:00:00
2013-02-27  01:00:00  20:00:00  21:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  20:00:00  21:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  01:00:00  02:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  09:00:00  10:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  02:00:00  03:00:00
2013-03-01  01:00:00  00:00:00  01:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  21:00:00  22:00:00
2013-02-28  01:00:00  22:00:00  23:00:00
2013-03-01  01:00:00  02:00:00  03:00:00
```

and i get this from my echo...

```
Delete 2013-02-28  12:00:00  13:00:00
Delete 2013-02-28  20:00:00  21:00:00
Delete 2013-03-01  00:00:00  01:00:00
Delete 2013-02-28  21:00:00  22:00:00
Delete 2013-02-28  22:00:00  23:00:00
Delete 2013-03-01  02:00:00  03:00:00
```

so if the current time is 2013-02-28 15:25:00 as it is now,it isnt supposed to show dates that are lower-2013-02-28  12:00:00  13:00:00.

Comment: what are columns: `date` and `start`?

Comment: Kindly echo the query and table description

Comment: Can you please setup a dummy table on mysqlfiddle?
And I **strongly** suggest that you use mysqli instead of mysql.

Comment: Probaly change your `CONCAT(date,' ',start)` function to something using `STR_TO_DATE(str,format)` see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: i added the tables now...

Comment: for me is working see and adapt http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcda3/7

Answer (score 0):

I assume `date` is a `Date` type and both `start` and `end` are something like a `Char` type column. 
You should use a `DateTime` type for both your `start` and `end` column so you don't need to do any concat. 
Now you can just do `start > NOW()`.

Comment: i am sorry i didnt mention it but date is type date and start and end are time types...so when i concat date and start i get-- Y-m-d H:i:s as the same format of the NOW() function but it still shows some dates that are lower,can this be because of a different timezone?

Comment: You are comparing a string with a datetime, so that's apples and oranges. you should use `STR_TO_DATE()` as mentioned in comments above or use my suggestion which will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need STR_TO_DATE() function to convert a string to a valid date value.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,date,start,end FROM jos_jxtc_appbook_appointments WHERE userident='$idusera' AND STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(date,' ',start))>NOW()");
```

Comment: i tried your code but i get...Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource...